# How do I solve this specific ordinary differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have no clue how to solve this ode , I've been watching videos, searching online, but I just can't, someone please help me.

$$2xyy' = x^2 + xy$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2xyy%27%3Dx%5E2%2Bxy It looks quite hard

Comment: Try substituting $z=\frac{y}{x}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's separable if you substitute $y=tx$
and $y'=t+xt'$
$$2y'=\frac x y+1$$
$$2(t+xt')=\frac 1 t+1$$
$$2xt'=\frac 1 t+1-2t$$
$$ 2xdt=(\frac 1 t +1 -2t)dx$$
$$ \int  \frac 1 {2x}dx=\int\frac {tdt} { 1+t-2t^2}$$
$$ \frac {\ln(x)} {2}+K=\int\frac {tdt} {(1-t)(1+2t)}$$

Comment: How come that the  part tdx , of the y' =  tdx +  xdt   became zero?

Comment: Wil add a line to make things more clear... \n more clear now ?

Comment: Is it more clear now @FernandoGardeazabal